# How to turn off vibration of Notifications in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-audiomanager, android-vibration, notification-listener

I'm developing an app that handles **sound and vibration** of apps' **notifications**. I am listening to notifications using `NotificationListenerService`. I am able to **turn on or off** notification's sound using `AudioManager` as follows:

```
// It turns off notification's sound
myAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true); 

// It turns on notification's sound
myAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
```

I have also tried to turn on or off notification's **vibration** with following code but it didn't work on my phone which has Android KitKat 4.4.4

```
// to turn off notification's vibration
myAudioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);

// to turn on notification's vibration
myAudioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did. In my NotificationListenerService, I cancel the original notification, turn off its vibration, and send it out again. Code like this should work:

```
Integer key = 1;

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Notification n = sbn.getNotification();
    if (doINeedToDisableVibration(sbn)) {
        cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
        n.defaults &= ~Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        n.vibrate = null;
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            synchronized(key) {
                nm.notify(key++, n);
            }
    }
}
```

In doINeedToDisableVibration(sbn), either make sure that vibration is on in the notification, or else check that sbn.packageName is NOT the same as your own package name, or you have a danger of generating an endless loop.

I am not sure this will work with all notifications. But it did work with MMS notifications on my HTC One A9 with 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

setVibrateSetting api is deprecated in API 16. As per android developer site,

> Applications should maintain their own vibrate policy based on current ringer mode that can be queried via getRingerMode().

So, you try with Ringer mode to enable/disable vibration.

```
 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

for setting silent mode :

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

For normal mode :

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

For ring vibrate mode:

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

Comment: It will affect phone to be on silent mode, normal mode and vibrate mode. I need to handle notifications only.

Comment: you can try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235609/how-to-mute-sound-and-vibration-for-all-notifications-in-android-5-0

For now, i am not getting any other solution.. set notification vibration is deprecated from api 16

Comment: Though it doesn't solve my issue, thanks for your time!

Comment: The link is helpful!