# Android NotificationListenerService : prevent notification from being displayed

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to make an advanced "do not disturb" app, so I'm using the NotificationListenerService from the SDK. Whenever onNotificationPosted fires, I am able to cancel the notification and remove it from the notification drawer. However, the phone still vibrates for half a second and the user it still aware of the notification, rendering the whole app less useful.

Would you know how to solve this and effectively prevent the phone from ringing/vibrating at all ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To turn off notification's sound, use the `AudioManager` as follows:

```
// Turn off sound
mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true); 

// Turn on sound
mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
```

Turning vibration off is more tricky

`setVibrateSetting` api is deprecated in API 16. As per [android developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setVibrateSetting(int, int)),

> Applications should maintain their own vibrate policy based on current ringer mode that can be queried via getRingerMode().

An ugly workaround is using the Ringer mode to enable/disable vibration with `RINGER_MODE_SILENT`. **This will mute the whole phone (incoming phone calls and notifications)**.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

And restore it to the previous state after a few seconds or in the end of the `onNotificationPosted` event when the notification is displayed.

---

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765481/how-to-turn-off-vibration-of-notifications-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235609/how-to-mute-sound-and-vibration-for-all-notifications-in-android-5-0)

Comment: Answer doesn't match the actual question. Where's the `NotificationListenerService` part in your answer? Although, OP should've included some code in his question.